# Python: Detecting Rect of Edges In Image & Cropping It Into a Square?

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I've figured out how to detect edges in an image using PIL (images will mostly be white background with black drawing marks). How can I detect the rectangle that encompasses these edges so that I can crop the image.

For example, I'd like to crop something like this:

[image]

into:

[image]

or this:

[image]

into:

[image]

I'm familiar with cropping in PIL except I don't know how to auto center around an object.

## Update:

I've managed to detect the edges by doing the following:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
image = Image.open("myImage.png")
image = image.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
```

How would I get the rect containing all these edges?

[image]

Comment: Ooh, that should be quite difficult. How do you know where this 'key feature' is? That's interesting, though

Comment: Oh by key feature I meant any marks (in the example above it's the entire number 3) it would try to crop it so that all marks fit into the new cropped image.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it e.g with opencv

```
import cv2

#Load the image in black and white (0 - b/w, 1 - color).
img = cv2.imread('input.png', 0)

#Get the height and width of the image.
h, w = img.shape[:2]

#Invert the image to be white on black for compatibility with findContours function.
imgray = 255 - img
#Binarize the image and call it thresh.
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#Find all the contours in thresh. In your case the 3 and the additional strike
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#Calculate bounding rectangles for each contour.
rects = [cv2.boundingRect(cnt) for cnt in contours]

#Calculate the combined bounding rectangle points.
top_x = min([x for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
top_y = min([y for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
bottom_x = max([x+w for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
bottom_y = max([y+h for (x, y, w, h) in rects])

#Draw the rectangle on the image
out = cv2.rectangle(img, (top_x, top_y), (bottom_x, bottom_y), (0, 255, 0), 2)
#Save it as out.jpg
cv2.imwrite('out.jpg', img)
```

Example output[image]

Comment: I haven't installed opencv yet (Having trouble) but it would be nice if you could comment your code :) I'll try to test it out soon.

Comment: Does openCV returns Width and height of rectangles or right and bottom coordinates with th boundingRect call? if it is width and height  and not coordinates, the code above won't work - in a very broken way. If it is coordinates, you could name them x1, y1, x2, y2 instead of x, y, w, h.

Comment: @jsbueno `boundingRect` returns top-left corner coordinates and rect width and heigth. Why it doesnt work?

Comment: @jsbueno in opposite `cv2.rectangle` takes top-left and bottom-right coordinates, so bottom-right we can get by calculating `x+w, y+h`

Comment: Because you are taking "max" and passing "w" and "h" - it will work if you just pass "..., x + w, y + h)" to the calls to max above.